# Limit bit position of two variables before arithmetic to prevent integer overflow

Tags: c, integer-overflow

I'm trying to limit arithmetic operations before they are executed to the result of at most 32 bit integers, specifically for addition.

This loop will find the bit position:

```
 size_t highestOneBitPosition(uint32_t a) {
     size_t bits=0;
     while (a!=0) {
         ++bits;
         a>>=1;
     };
     return bits;
 }
```

This function effectively limits multiplication:

```
 bool multiplication_is_safe(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
     size_t a_bits=highestOneBitPosition(a), b_bits=highestOneBitPosition(b);
     return (a_bits+b_bits<=32);
 }
```

However, I'm unsure how to do this with addition. Something like this:

```
bool addition_is_safe(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
size_t a_bits=highestOneBitPosition(a), b_bits=highestOneBitPosition(b);
return (a_bits<32 && b_bits<32);
}
```

However, this will not limit the integer to 32bit (or 0x7FFFFFFF for signed). It will make sure each operand has has that many bit positions.

Mathematically, if you add two numbers, you have at most a carry of 1 into the place beyond the longest. So if you add a 4 digit number to a 3 digit number (or anything 4 digits or less), you have at most a 5 digit number. Except, when you have two with the same, you can end up with more (99 * 99 = 9801) so then it would be the same concept as in multiplication (a_bits+b_bits <=32)

What I would have to do is determine the longest operand, then add 1 and make sure that it's not exceeding 32 bit positions. I am entirely unsure how to do this with a function. My question is how can I modify addition_is_safe(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) to limit the result to <=32 as it is in multiplication_is_safe. I definitely want to utilize the HighestOneBit Position with this.

Comment: What? That function already works. Not for signed no, but then it was never intended to do that.

Comment: `return INT_MAX - a < b;` probably?

Comment: Yes it works but it does not limit the result to a 32bit position unless I implemented it wrong. In my program it exceeded 32bit (0x7FFFFFFF) by far. The truth is, I would like to stay congruent with addition to also use bit position instead of a different solution since utilizing bit position is somewhat interesting to me.

Comment: But the 32 bit limit is 0xFFFFFFFF, unless you mean signed, and then this method is not applicable.

Comment: Yes you are right, 0x7FFFFFFF is the limit for signed. For this purpose, I just want to implement a ceiling for research purposes and 0x7FFFFFFF seems to be a good number tho I would be ok with increasing it. This solution should be applicable to unsigned (I don't care about negative numbers right now).

Comment: If you're trying to use a method for unsigned but fit the result into a non-negative signed 32-bit number, your effective limit is 31 bits, not 32...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't even think that this function is correct:

```
bool multiplication_is_safe(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
     size_t a_bits=highestOneBitPosition(a), b_bits=highestOneBitPosition(b);
     return (a_bits+b_bits<=32);
}
```

It does return `false` when the multiply will overflow, but it also returns `false` when the multiply doesn't overflow.  For example, given a = `0x10000` and b = `0x8000`, this function returns `false` even though the result of a*b is `0x80000000` which fits in 32 bits.  But if you change a and b to `0x1ffff` and `0xffff` (which have the same "highest one bit positions") then the multiply actually **does** overflow.  But you couldn't tell by just using the highest bit position.  You would need to look at more than just the top bit to figure out whether the multiplication will overflow.  In fact, you would need to do part or all of the actual multiplication to figure out the right answer.

Similarly, you could construct a function `addition_is_safe` that detects "possible overflows" (both in the positive and negative direction) using bit positions.  But you can't detect "actual overflow" unless you do part or all of the actual addition.

I believe that in the worst case, you will be forced to do the full multiplication or addition, so I'm not sure you will be saving anything by not letting the machine just do the full multiplication/addition for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Mathematically, if you add two numbers, you have at most a carry of 1
>   into the place beyond the longest.

That's absolutely correct (for unsigned binary numbers) without exception; you just got lost in your further consideration. So, the *addition_is_safe* condition based on the summands' numbers of bits is: the highest number of bits of the summands has to be smaller than the available number of bits.

```
bool addition_is_safe(uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    size_t a_bits=highestOneBitPosition(a), b_bits=highestOneBitPosition(b);
    return (a_bits<b_bits?b_bits:a_bits)<32;
}
```

Surely you are aware that a `false` return from that function doesn't always mean overflow would occur, but a `true` return means overflow cannot occur.

Answer (score -1):

you can check for overflow from adding two positive integers with `(a + b) < a || (a + b) < b`

overflow will either make the value negative (for signed integers), or will leave a smaller positive mode 32 remainder (for unsigned)

a positive added to a negative will never overflow

two negatives should be similar to two positives

Comment: I would like to do this integer overflow check before the arithmetic is performed thus the bit position counter.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your purpose, unless this is homework, but in C the addition test will be faster than a bit counter loop.  With addition, just testing the bit position is not enough, you also need to test all the intervening carry-outs.  1110 + 0001 does not overflow, but 1110 + 0010 does.  You either duplicate the work the addition is doing propagating carries, or you make the addition do it for you.

Comment: Yes this is for homework purpose on a topic I chose, in this case utilizing the bit position. You are right that this approach is slower. About the 0's, the HighestBit function will find the HighestOneBit so they are not a concern :). I suppose my question is how can I modify addition_is_safe(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) to limit the result to <=32 as it is in multiplication_is_safe. :)

Comment: you mean `(a + b) > a || (a + b) > b` where a, b are two's complement signed 32-bit integers does not detect overflow?  please explain

Comment: Signed overflow is undefined, as soon as it has happened (more precisely, as soon as it is certain that it will happen), the actions of your program become indeterminate. In practice this means that e.g. Gcc optimizes such tests out in some cases.

Comment: it's undefined in a programming language, yes, but it is defined at the hardware (cpu and register) level.  The actions of the program remain deterministic, it's only the data values that are said to be undefined (undefined because it's implementation dependent, not because it's unknown).  Perhaps you could provide an example?

Comment: This is about C, not about assembler (and you mentioned signed and unsigned integers, which, for addition (for 2's complement), don't differ either on a hardware level). For UB (and some commentary on signed integer overflow), see for example [here](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).

Comment: And btw, you can use @mafso etc to notify people (I wouldn't have read your responses if I hadn't had the tab still open).